# Efficient way to select most recent index with finite value in column from Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to find the most recent index with a value that is not 'NaN' relative to the current index. So, say I have a DataFrame with 'NaN' values like this:

```
       A       B       C
0    2.1     5.3     4.7
1    5.1     4.6     NaN
2    5.0     NaN     NaN
3    7.4     NaN     NaN
4    3.5     NaN     NaN
5    5.2     1.0     NaN
6    5.0     6.9     5.4
7    7.4     NaN     NaN
8    3.5     NaN     5.8
```

If I am currently at index 4, I have the values:

```
       A       B       C
4    3.5     NaN     NaN
```

I want to know the last known value of 'B' relative to index 4, which is at index `1`:

```
       A       B       C
1    5.1   -> 4.6    NaN
```

I know I can get a list of all indexes with NaN values using something like:

```
indexes = df.index[df['B'].apply(np.isnan)]
```

But this seems inefficient in a large database. Is there a way to `tail` just the last one relative to the current index?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to have the value `4.6` and the index `1`.

Comment: Do you just want to know the most recent index at index `4` or you want to know for all of the indices?

Comment: For this case, just the one at the index of lookup (which in the example is 4).

Answer (score 5):

You may try something like this, convert the `index` to a series that have the same `NaN` values as column `B` and then use `ffill()` which carries the last non missing index forward for all subsequent `NaN`s:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['Last_index_notnull'] = df.index.to_series().where(df.B.notnull(), np.nan).ffill()
df['Last_value_notnull'] = df.B.ffill()
df
```

[image]

Now at index `4`, you know the last non missing value is `4.6` and index is `1`.

Answer (score 5):

some useful methods to know

***`last_valid_index`***
***`first_valid_index`***
for columns `B` as of index `4`

```
df.B.ix[:4].last_valid_index()

1
```

you can use this for all columns in this way

```
pd.concat([df.ix[:i].apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index) for i in df.index],
          axis=1).T
```

[image]